# Catching process termination when piped

Tags: node.js, unix, process, pipe

I have a node CLI program which runs forever and which should print an summary right before the process terminates. I have registered these events to act before termination:

```
process.on("exit", end);
process.on("SIGINT", end);
process.on("SIGQUIT", end);
process.on("SIGTERM", end);
```

Above callbacks run when started with `node app`, but not when the process is piped like `node app | tee file` in which case, I won't receive either a SIGINT, nor does the `exit` callback run. Any suggestions?

Comment: It works for me (`exit` event). I tested on node v0.10.31 on Linux. What node version are you trying with?

Comment: I'm on node v0.10.35, the program is interrupted by SIGINT, if that matters.

Comment: Happens on both Linux and OS X for me. If you wanna check it out: `npm install -g tcpie && tcpie google.com | tee /dev/null` and then SIGINT it.

Comment: Interestingly, It behaves correctly when stopping it with `kill -s SIGINT pid`, it's just the CTRL-C, which doesn't seem to trigger either event when piped.

Comment: I'm now certain that the callbacks get called, but with stdout still piped, the output I print never reaches the terminal. Printing to stderr instead does work, but that's an ugly hack.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this with a check for `process.stdout._type === "pipe"`, in which case I output to `stderr` instead of `stdout`. Not a pretty solution, but it does what I need.